# load files to the public files dir via admin panel?

Tags: 7, files

I was wondering if I could get some advice on best practice on loading images directly to the public files DIR - without FTP access?

My site lives on cloud hosting, and I have no FTP access, my code pushes go through git, but my files dir is not included in the git repo.
I have to load a couple images that are not part of any content type to the public files dir, and don't know if there is a module for that, or what other best practices may be.
I *can* put a support ticket in if I have to, but I'd like to see if I can get around that if it's possible

Thanks!

Comment: I'm testing the media module right now to see if it's a good answer, I'll close this question if it is

Comment: if not, there is nothing wrong with keeping icons and other module or theme images with the theme or module, eg, in `sites/all/modules/YOURMODULE/images/foo.jpg` or `sites/all/themes/modules/YOURTHEME/images/bar.jpg` and then you should be able to use git to push them up in there.

Comment: for this instance thats what i ended up doing, the Media mod may work in the future for larger loads, but I also was able to to work with the theme for this one file/one instance

Answer (score 1):

Since my user case was only one image, I ended up putting the file in the theme folder.
for future and larger number file loads I'll be using the media module